# Can I use MOL to solve 2D steady state PDE in terms of r and z spatial coordinates?

Tags: pde, finite-difference, numerics, finite-volume, numerical-modelling

recently I need to solve a 2D steady state PDE equation.
It’s not time dependent, and the only two independent variables are z and r direction.

[image]

So far for this solution, I was thinking using Method of Lines (MOL) to semi-discretize only the r radius direction and source term, leaving the spatial z coordinate and Temperature to be treated with ODE solver, ex:ODE45.

My question is: Is this the correct way to solve this 2D steady state PDE by MOL?
Since in general MOL is mostly dealing with one time dependent variable and one spatial coordinate in general PDEs.  Thus, I’m not sure if z spatial coordinate in this case, could be considered using implicit way to be solved (just like time step) ??

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For MOL, it does not have to be time, you can use it for your z variable just fine.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It really helps me. Because I’m not so sure before.. One more question, then will z be solved in ODE solver in a explicit way or implicit way?

Comment: But that depends on the ODE solver - if the algorithm there is implicit then in the integration in the time-like variable z will  be implicit.

Comment: Dear Maxim Umansky, thank you very much. With these infos, it really helps me to develop my codes further.

Comment: Dear @MaximUmansky Sir, I am struggling with the heat source term when it comes to control volume discretization. I wonder if you could please give me some advice…    https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4576439/heat-source-discretization-in-control-volume-by-fvm

Comment: Ok - I can look, what's the problem there?

Comment: @MaximUmansky, here is kink to my question:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4576439/heat-source-discretization-in-control-volume-by-fvm

Comment: I’m not sure if my source enthalpy term (J/m^3 )is correct or not.

Comment: It would be helpful to draw a sketch of the finite-volume grid that you are using, from that you should be able to see the metric coefficients used for discretization of the equation.

Comment: Dear @MaximUmansky, thank you very much Sir! I’ve then decided use the kinetic expression term to simulate my problem. However, I got another issue for the distribution for my concentration data in radius…… Would you mind taking a look at this question that I jus post? : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4602469/how-to-calculate-concentration-distribution-in-radius-correctly-with-boundary-co